# How to initialise a list of arrays in c sharp?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I initialize a list of arrays?

```
public void createRect()
{
  Rectangles[] rect = new Rectangles[];
  List<Rectangles> rect= new <Rectangles>();
}
```

I tried with these two statements but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need a list, which contains the objects of Rectangle.
You may try following:

```
List<Rectangle> rec = new List<Rectangle>();
for(int i=0; i<YourCustomSize; i++)
  rec.Add(new Rectangle(){ Property1 = Value1, Property2 = Value2, ...});
```

Comment: Thank you Sir., Here exact what you are assuming is correct here I got the solution

Answer (score 1):

Try `var rectList = new List<Rectangle[]>();`

`List rect = new ();` doesn't make sense. You need to follow the `new` keyword with what you want to create. eg. `List rect = new List<Rectangle[]>();`

Comment: thank you for giving solution sir.., but how can we add new rectagles to my rect list array

Comment: Do you want a list of array of rectangles, or just a list of rectangles? Do a little more research on what Arrays and Lists are in C#. 

You can add an array to your list of arrays using: rect.add(ArrayOfRects).

Also, if an answer was the correct one for your question, you should accept it.

Comment: I am new to c# I want to create array of rectangles i tried with  `List<Rectangle> rectList = new List<Rectangle>();` but it didn't give the solution

Comment: Then you need to be clear about that in your question. 'List of array' and 'array' are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

array is list with fixed length. So you must initialize it with length for this array. For example: if you need five element of array, you can initialize by:

```
Rectangles[] rect = new Rectangles[5];
```

please refer to [array for c#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

So if you need to create list of array:

```
Rectangles[] rect1 = new Rectangles[5];
rect1[0] = new Rectangles();
rect1[1] = new Rectangles();
rect1[2] = new Rectangles();
rect1[3] = new Rectangles();
rect1[4] = new Rectangles();

Rectangles[] rect2 = new Rectangles[3];
rect2[0] = new Rectangles();
rect2[1] = new Rectangles();
rect2[2] = new Rectangles();

List<Rectangles[]> rectList= new List<Rectangles[]>();
rectList.Add(rect1);
rectList.Add(rect2);
```

Comment: He needs to create a list of arrays, not a single array.

Comment: thank you for giving solution sir.., but how can we add new rectagles to my rect list array

Comment: @Osiris,@rangasathish: thank for your correction. I have update it.